# Configuring Solaris 11 Audit

Tags: logs, solaris, audit

Recently I was working trying to activate the *solaris audit service* to record logs and write them in a single file in */var/adm/auditlog*.

The thing is, I was trying to find some useful info about it over internet and I could not found it too much.

First, I checked the audit service status with **auditconfig -getcond** and it is Enable, I disable the audit service using *-t* parameter with the command audit. (**audit -t**). And enable it again with root user.

I have the default auditing parameters (*audit_event*, *audit_class*, *policies*, etc). And I don't know where these logs are written or I don't know how can I make that the audit logs saved in a single file.

Please, any help with my case?.

See ya,

Comment: It sounds like you want to have `syslog` log the audit records. See [How to Configure syslog Audit Logs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1456/audittask-14.html#SYSADV6audittask-11)

Comment: Hello Mark, Im having a problem and Im a little bit stuck, I installed a clean Solaris 11.3 version in a VirtualBox as a Virtualization Software Management, and I did these steps. **auditconfig -getcond** --> It shows me the audit is enable. Auditing. Also, I did the steps that Oracle site describes me and I could not obtain that audit logs can be saved in the syslog on **/var/** directory. I launched this commands **auditconfig -getflags** and **auditconfig -getnaflags** and I obtain the default Solaris 11.3 configuration by default, I did not change anything about this config.

Comment: Also, I saw the auditing policy using this command: **auditconfig -getpolicy** and I have the **cnt** active as default.

About the audit plugins, I used this command: **auditconfig -getplugin** and I have **audit_binfile** plugin, **audit_syslog** active and **audit_remote** inactive.

I edited the **/etc/syslog.conf** file and add this line: **audit.notice /var/adm/auditlog**. I dont know what Im doing wrong :(.

Comment: If you use the [logger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/logger-1.html) command to send some text to audit.notice, does it appear in the auditlog file?

Comment: Hello Mark, I use this command: logger system rebooted and it does not write me anything in the auditlog file in /var/ directory. Any help?.

Comment: Hello, any help from somebody that knows how to solve my problem?.

Comment: Type `logger -p audit.notice hi there`. Does it appear in `/var/adm/auditlog` ?

Comment: Hello Mark, nothing. I did not how can I make that auditing service writes on a custom file, in this case on /var/adm/auditlog. :(.

Comment: You can make syslogd write to any existing file by editing its config file (which you did) and you can make the audit system send records to syslogd. Let's get syslogd working first. Can you show the output of `ls -l /var/adm/auditlog` ?

Comment: Oks Mark, here my configs about each part of auditing service. I have setted the directory by default on the auditing service wrotes messages.[Image Solaris 11 Auditing Service](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/ca143ef2)

Comment: Mark, here is the output of auditlog file: **-rw-r--r--   1 root     root           0 jun 29 14:44 auditlog**.

Comment: Interesting. The modification time of the file is earlier today. Since the file is empty, I expected its mod time to be June 18, when you first made the syslogd changes. Did you run a log rotation program today? If so, are there any older versions of that auditlog file in the /var/adm directory?

Comment: Not, those files shows that modification date because I was re-creating the test by yesterday in a new server.

Comment: Hi Mark, if I use this command **auditconfig -setplugin audit_syslog active p_flags=lo,-fr,+fc,+fd,ad,am,na,as,ua,+aa,ss USER** it will work as well for an specific user?.

Comment: Hello, any update of this main topic?.

Answer (score 3):

If you kept everything out-of-the-box: 
Did you look into /var/audit . Keep in mind that in the default configuration of Solaris the files are in a binary format. You need to look at them with the praudit command.

Comment: Is not needed other configuration files to do the auditing service work as well in Solaris 11?. I was watching some files, such as audit_control, audit_user into /etc/security directory. Any idea of an example of how to config them?.

Answer (score 0):

What does `auditconfig -getcond` show you?

This would show you some of the base config options, and where the binary audit data is going:

`auditconfig -getplugin audit_binfile`

Plugin: audit_binfile (active)
        Attributes: p_age=0h;p_dir=/var/audit;p_fsize=0;p_minfree=1

Have you checked the audit services in SMF?  As well as the others in case something that auditd depends on is in maintenance?
ie:  `svcs -a |grep audit; svcs -xv`

I asked about the first, as for some reason on one of my Solaris 11 systems, the auditd service fails to start, and I've been unable to find a way to kick it to life.

[Auditing in Oracle Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1456/audittm-1.html#scrolltoc)

Comment: auditconfig -getcond ==> this command shows me: auditing. And the service is Enable and working as well.

Comment: So, it sounds like it's working, so you should see audit files in "p_dir" which will require an auditreduce/praudit to view.  Or check out the link  Mark Plotnick gave you to configure syslog auditing.